# Swift Error – Attempting to add a Parent node as a Child node

Tags: swift, nodes, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on trying to take a `.dae` file I have and display it once it recognises the first image file I have in photos. Unfortunately, I am receiving an error that a parent node is being added as a child node and not understanding where this is happening.

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class PlaneTrackingViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ARPlaneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ARPlaneView.delegate = self

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/LoadScene.scn")!

        ARPlaneView.scene = scene
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else {print ("No Images Available")
            return
        }

        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
        ARPlaneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        ARPlaneView.session.pause()
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer:SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode()

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.6)

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            let motorScene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/ACMotor/ACMotor.dae")!
            let motorNode = motorScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!

            motorNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
            motorNode.position.z = 0.3

            motorNode.addChildNode(motorNode)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }           
        return node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should be written this way: `scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)`

or in your case:

```
motorScene.rootNode.addChildNode(motorNode)
```

Comment: Thank you ! idk why I didn't see the issue before. Though, I tried implementing "motorScene.rootNode.addChildNode(motorNode)" and tried "(planeNode.addChildNode(motorNode)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)". Both left me with errors saying ("Scene <SCNScene: 0x2813bfde0> is modified within a rendering callback of another scene ")

Comment: What are you connecting to what? Give me a draft, please!

Comment: What's `let scene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/LoadScene.scn")!` for?

Comment: You can use `let motorScene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/ACMotor/ACMotor.dae")!` as a primary scene.

Comment: Just like our favourite ship: `let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!`

Comment: That worked! the LoadScene.scn was just an empty scn. I didn't need it. I took (ARPlaneView.scene = motorScene) and placed it at the bottom of my renderer func. Now everything seems to work besides my object following the trackingposition of my phone  after it reads the image.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
motorNode.addChildNode(motorNode)
```

Tells me that you're trying to add `motorNode` into `motorNode`, and this is clearly the error here - you're adding a node into itself.